# Is it possible for different published OAuth 2.0 Client IDs across one or more projects to use the same Redirect URI?

Tags: google-oauth

Is it possible for different OAuth 2.0 Client ID across one or more platforms to use the same Redirect URI?

In other words, does Google Cloud Platform restrict Authorized redirect URIs to a single project? Or can multiple OAuth 2.0 clients in separate cloud projects use the same app URI.

Use cases for this include: A Production Client in one project, and a published for client (perhaps for access to beta features in another) ?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to use same redirected uri for multiple projects, you just have to set the redirected uri and it will work perfectly fine